# Show heapsort repeats comparisons

Tags: algorithm, sorting, heap, heapsort

how would one prove that heapsort repeats comparisons that it has made before? (i.e. it would perform a comparison that has been done previously)
Thanks

Comment: Try working out (on paper or with some code) what the algorithm would do to sort the array (0,1,2,3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two elements may take comparisons in build heap step(heapify) and also in reorder step in heap sort. This is [the wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort).

For example, sort by max-heap:

- origin array:  4 6 10 7 3 8 5
- `heapify` to a new heap array by `shift-up`.
  The comparisons: 4<6, 6<10, 4<7, 6<8
  (10) (7 8) (4 3 6 5)  // each layer is grouped by parenthesis
- re-order step

  - swap the first with the last, put the big one to end
  - reduce the heap size by 1
  - use `shift-down`
    The comparisons: 5<8, 6<7, 3<6, 3<4, 3<5, 3<4

Because, in the `heapify` the comparisons based on the order of elements. And after `heapify`, the order may be not sorted too. So there may be other comparisons.